# production build - dont open app

Tags: angular, deployment

I am sorry for this short question. I don't know how to deploy angular2 app so I don't know what to write to help me. I need to deploy production. When I run this command `npm build -prod`, its ok, copy all js and html to dist folder, but when I open index.html in browser app don't start and in the log is this:

```
/E:/styles.a530fc809103522200ce.bundle.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
inline.64b91d2d61fb76e9d35a.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills.fe38fa94cd758b43a148.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
scripts.42e3c7ff6b40c17280bd.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
vendor.7b7007a424e50f334b56.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.5f1b617b49bf3e0d0eaa.bundle.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a function TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///E:/User/antos/Dokumenty/Projects/PCL%20VA/ProLight/ProLight.Client/dist/index.html:26:21)
    at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30203)
    at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30517) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2
/E:/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:26)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

I don't know where can be a problem and I don't know which files I must show you. Please tell me which files you want to see.

Comment: in `dev` mode a webpack-dev-server is running, do u have a nodejs server to serve the `dist` files ? What is the url are u visiting in your browser ?

Comment: You need to host the app on a server.

Comment: It is next problem. I dont have nodejs server, i use IIS. I tried open only index.html in browser and i thought that it is work.

Comment: I can not open only index.html? i build app to js and index.html i have linked js files. So can i host app on IIS server or i must nodejs?

Comment: u can use IIS u just need to configure it to serve static files

Comment: Please tell me how

Comment: check out this link https://forums.iis.net/t/1221923.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied builded files to folder in server. I added web.config and added app to IIS DefaultAppPool. And I get this errors:

```
        GET http://server/inline.64b91d2d61fb76e9d35a.bundle.js 
    server/:36 GET 
http://server/polyfills.fe38fa94cd758b43a148.bundle.js 
    server/:17 GET 
http://server/styles.a530fc809103522200ce.bundle.css 
    server/:36 GET 
http://server/scripts.42e3c7ff6b40c17280bd.bundle.js 
    server/:36 GET 
http://server/vendor.7b7007a424e50f334b56.bundle.js 
    server/:36 GET 
http://server/main.5f1b617b49bf3e0d0eaa.bundle.js 
    (index):36 GET 
http://server/inline.64b91d2d61fb76e9d35a.bundle.js 
    (index):36 GET 
http://server/polyfills.fe38fa94cd758b43a148.bundle.js 
    (index):36 GET 
http://server/scripts.42e3c7ff6b40c17280bd.bundle.js 
    (index):36 GET 
http://server/vendor.7b7007a424e50f334b56.bundle.js 
    (index):36 GET 
http://server/main.5f1b617b49bf3e0d0eaa.bundle.js 
    jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).select2 is not a function TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://sigma913/ProLight.Client/:26:21)
        at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30203)
        at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30517) undefined
    r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2
    k @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2
    jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):26)
        at j (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
        at k (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

Here is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
           <clear />
            <add 
                name="StaticFile" 
                path="*" verb="*" 
                modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
                resourceType="Either" 
                requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```